# In Sublime Text 2, search for a folder

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2, and I'm looking for an entire folder within my currently loaded directory, which is pretty large.

I understand there are many effective ways to search for files with specific folders or the whole directory, but I'm searching for the folder *itself*, not any specific files in it. I've tried using the `GoTo Anything` feature, but it only seems to look for files, not folders.

Answer (score 0):

Go "Project->Add Folder to Project". Select your folder and then appears a col in left. Only right click in your parent folder and: "Find in Folder..."
Hope helps ;)

Comment: This searches for files within that folder and it's subfolders, not for folders themselves.

Comment: Ahhh. You want to search "the subfolder's name". Uff. In this case i don't know. Sorry